# How do you describe the sensation of mist from a river?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is the following sentence correct, to describe the refreshing feeling when one is near a river.

"We listen to the murmur and feel the brisk of the river"

When I looked up the definition for brisk, I found:

[image]

On the 3rd option: "brisk" is used to describe the wind as stimulating and invigorating, which is a similar meaning/expression I would like to convey.

Comment: brisk is an adjective; the noun is briskness. However, allow me to point out that a mist is not usually brisk. A mist is moist but does not really move. Though a brisk wind could blow mist in from the sea.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Are you requesting words/phrases, or asking us to check your sentence, or asking if "brisk" is the right word for that context?

Comment: Why not say "refreshing mist" from the river? or "the brisk scent of the river"?

Comment: What @Tᴚoɯɐuo said. You need a credible ***noun*** to be modified by "brisk". But note that whereas the collocation [***brisk ocean air***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22brisk+ocean+air%22) is so common as to be practically a cliche, we don't normally think that way about air that happens to have (usually, *briefly*) passed over a ***river***. Effectively, your problem is you're trying to convey a concept that wouldn't actually mean much (or at least, be *familiar*) to the average Anglophone. I certainly don't get any useful ideas in my head when I try to imagine the context.

Comment: Ah - maybe fine droplets of water thrown up by a very fast-moving "whitewater" river such as people might go kayaking on. But when they pull over to the bank, would kayakers really notice that insignificant extra water in the air?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely missing the correct noun.  Your sentence, besides being awkward, seems to be saying the river is brisk...sort of.  But that's not what you're trying to say.

You're in present tense so perhaps: 
"We listen to the murmer of the river and feel the brisk mist rising from it's surface with the wind seemingly blowing it directly our way".

I don't know.  Like most of you, I didn't need to research the sentence to know that it was grammatically incorrect.  A poorly written sentence immediately reveals itself to me as *wrong*. The sentence I suggested above is a far cry from the original which may be outside the scope of what we are supposed to provide.

However, I did find an interesting noun that could possibly be used in place of 
"a brisk mist" I believe: brume.

brume
noun
poetic heavy mist or fog
Derived Forms
brumous , adjective
Word Origin for brume
C19: from French: mist, winter, from Latin brūma , contracted from brevissima diēs the shortest day

I found that at thesaurus.com.  Another consideration possibly already mentioned, is spray (although "spray" can be either chilly or warm so it would, by necessity, need to be prefaced with the adjective "brisk").

"We listen to the murmur and feel the *brume* of the river".
I still don't like it.  Although the definition of brume implies cold it's not absolutely clear to me that "brume" would suffice without the adjective "brisk". The word "river" ought to be used at the beginning of the sentence as opposed to the end but I'll leave it at that. I hope that was a decent reply (by forum standards).

Comment: Nothing you say is wrong, but it's unclear how this is an answer to the question.  "Brume" is just an obscure (and possibly colloquial) synonym for "mist", and does not convey any particular *sensation*.  You might want to edit so that your argument reaches some kind of *emphatic* answer.